# Nested DIV with inline-block in Safari causes sibling elements of parent to be misaligned

Tags: safari, css

I am trying to align a set of "buttons" made out of `DIV` elements that are arranged along the bottom of a web page using the CSS `display: inline-block`. I've attached a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g00Lbqw/6/) which illustrates the issue.

The problem is that this current code works on all modern browsers *except* Safari (7, 8). I don't know if this is a bug in WebKit that Safari uses, or something that I've allowed to happen by not using the right incantations.

The thing that triggers the unwanted behavior is the nested `DIV.btn-sub`; however, removing that text is not an option to "fix" the issue.

Here's the expected behavior (snap taken from Firefox 34, similar behavior on IE 9, 10, and latest Chrome):

[image: Expected behavior]

Here's what happens on Safari:

[image: Unwanted behavior]

Any help here would be appreciated!

Comment: From the testing I have done, it seems to be the `padding-top: 15px` element of the class.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best practice to use a list when creating inline-blocked elements in a row/list, such as a navigation.

The issue here seems to be the block being set with a padding directly; relative it's parent. Which somehow is turning it into a margin or something similar.

You can try stripping CSS until you get a full height out of the blocks, and then add another inner div which you can call `.btn-padding` which contains your top padding.

Here is similar.

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: green;
}
#wrap {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    border:0;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
}

#btnls {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#btnls li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: purple;
    min-width: 158px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#btnls li .btn-padding {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#btnls li .btn-padding .sub-btn {
    display: block;
    font-size: x-small;   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <ul id="btnls">
        <li>
            <div class="btn-padding">Foo
                <div class="sub-btn">Bar</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="btn-padding">Foo</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="btn-padding">Foo</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```